# Why dynamically added tag (angular directive) gives undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have the following codes

CONTROLLERS.JS //inject cookieNotifier.html into index.html

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {

})
.directive('cookieNotification', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: '../Pages/cookieNotifier.html'
    }
})
```

cookieNotifier.html

```
<h4 id="cookieNotifier">

    This site uses cookies.
    By continuing to browse the site, you are agreeing to our use of cookies.

    <span><button id="acceptCookies">Got It</button></span>
</h4>
```

INDEX.HTML //here is the angular directive

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">

        <cookie-notification></cookie-notification>
```

And now in my client.js I want to check if cookies accepted, if so hide the 'cookie notification' bar

CLIENT.JS

```
$(window).ready(function() {

    var cookiesAccepted = localStorage.getItem('cookiesAccepted');

    if(cookiesAccepted === "true" || cookiesAccepted === null) {
        console.log($('#cookieNotifier').html());
        console.log("hide cookie notification bar")
    }
    else{
        console.log( "show cookie notification bar");
    }
```

When I want to hide/remove the h4 tag, it does nothing. It simply gives me undefined.

Comment: Include code for `cookieNotifier.html` as `#cookieNotifier` is not clear.

Comment: @AniketSinha  Sorry, forgot to paste the code

Comment: Are you getting undefined for `console.log($('#cookieNotifier').html());`?

Comment: @AniketSinha yes. I actually tried to hide by doing $('#cookieNotifier').hide() but nothing happened. Then put $('#cookieNotifier').html() in console.log and saw that it cannot see the html element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the
>   page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to
>   execute.

Refer [jquery ready doc](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Let me tell you the timeline of events:

- document is `ready`
- Angular app is initialized
- Your directive is called

What happens is your code:

```
if(cookiesAccepted === "true" || cookiesAccepted === null) {
    console.log($('#cookieNotifier').html());
    console.log("hide cookie notification bar")
}
```

runs even before angular app is initialized, which in turns calls your directive. so there will be no HTML element with id=`cookieNotifier`, hence the `undefined`

What you can do is move your showing/hiding logic into the directive itself. Modify your directive like this.

```
.directive('cookieNotification', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    templateUrl: '../Pages/cookieNotifier.html',
    link: function(scope,element,attributes) {
      var cookiesAccepted = localStorage.getItem('cookiesAccepted');
      if(cookiesAccepted === "true" || cookiesAccepted === null) {
        //console.log($('#cookieNotifier').html());
        //console.log("hide cookie notification bar");
        scope.showNotification = false;
      }
      else{
        //console.log( "show cookie notification bar");
        scope.showNotification = true;
      }
    }
 }
})
```

and then you can use `showNotification` in your template to show/hide the message.

```
<h4 id="cookieNotifier" ng-if="showNotification">

This site uses cookies.
By continuing to browse the site, you are agreeing to our use of cookies.

<span><button id="acceptCookies">Got It</button></span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the codes. It is working perfectly. Great code! :)